# Removing space between float and paragraph latex

Tags: floats

[image]

How to remove the gap or reduce the gap between figure and paragraphs? Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome, excellent Paint-foo.

Comment: Without any code, it is very hard to suggest anything. This gap might be there, because you have a twoside document and `\flushbuttom` is active. You could sove that using `\raggedbuttom`. Or there is another reason. Please [provide a minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) to get more detailed help.

Comment: no, this is to do with setting length of some parameters.

Comment: You need to show us the LaTeX source that creates the output you have posted. None of us is clairvoyant :-)